# Merging cells in Excel not working like it used to

Tags: microsoft-excel, merge, cell-format

For the last couple of weeks my excel 'merge cells' has not been working like it used to. I used to be able to make multiple selections (e.g. ctrl+two adjacent cells on row 1, ctrl+four cells on row 3, ctrl+four cells on row 5), click on the 'Merge Cells' button and each selection would merge.

Now, only the last-selected set of cells merges. It's very frustrating! Is it a setting I can change?
Thanks
Peter
(Office 365, version 1702 (Build 7870.2024))

Comment: On checking further, it seems like it's only the 'merge and centre' that's not working like it used to - the others work like I remember...

Comment: I've had the same thing. I managed to get round it by adding some data on an unused part of the spreadsheet, performing the **Merge cells** function and then using **Formatting Painter** to apply it to the data I'm interested in. Feels like it might be a bug to me...